# Stimulsoft Report Showing the same Color for all columns

Tags: reporting, stimulsoft

I Setup a condition in Stimulsoft - Cross Tabbed table to have the cell back-color display "Green" if it's value is Greater than a Number.  I added another condition to have the cell back-color display as "Red" if it's value is less than a number.

The report generated, displays all cells as Green.

How can I get the report to display the correct back-color based on the condition?

I'm using Stimulsoft 2014.1.1900

Here is my output:

Store_Number Net_Sales

```
19 *37060.5700*  
 43 *65500.1400*  
 13 *51757.6800*  
 32 *120306.5400*  
 15 *57593.2100*  
 19 *53917.7200*  
 26 *78487.1700*  
 90 *105606.6100*  
 14 *118246.8800*  
 55 *79873.8300*  
 Total 768350.3500
```

In Italic is the column that is showing up ALL green.  The numbers above 55000 should show up "green" below should show up "red"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditions in CrossTab are set different way.
You should use value variable. For example,

```
value <20
```

You could get more information in the [Stimulsoft User Manual](http://www.stimulsoft.com/en/documentation/online/user-manual/report_internals_crosstable_conditions.htm).